Making clear the definition of 'affine variety' in Mumford's book.
I am reading "The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes" by Mumford. In section 4 the author defines the term affine variety:

An affine variety is a topological space $X$ plus a sheaf of $k$-valued functions $\mathcal{O}_X$ on $X$ which is isomorphic to an irreducible algebraic subset of some $k^n$ plus the sheaf just defined.

There are a few things that are not clear to me.

When it says "which is isomorphic to", what is the "which" referring to? To the whole pair $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ or just $X$?
In any case, what is exactly the notion of "isomorphism" in this definition (and between what elements are we considering such isomorphism)?
Is "the sheaf just defined" refering to the sheaf of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X$? In the book, no other sheaf is considered (apart from the examples given after the definition of sheaf).

I feel like I need some insight overall.

Is the advantage of this definition that we "forget" about the ambient space $k^n$ and we look at affine varieties as topological spaces + a sheaf? If yes, why does the sheaf provide that much information?

Thanks a lot. Comments to give some context to the topic, even if they are not directly related to the question, are welcome.

I don't have the book at hand, has the concept of a "locally ringed space" been introduced?

You don't need the abstraction layer of LRS here -- these are sheaves of functions.

No, not yet. @Thorgott


To the pair. Just to $X$ would simply be a topological isomorphism, i.e., a homeomorphism. That's too weak. 2. I would say that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ are isomorphic, if there exists a homeomorphism $F: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $F^*: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism of sheaves. 3. Yes. 4. Presumably, this is answered in the book. The fact that the algebraic structure is uniquely determined by the sheaf of functions is what drives the theory of schemes.


Thanks a lot. Last question: For the homomorphism in (2), are we considering $k^n$ with Zariski's topology? Otherwise I think it is not a topological space if defined only as $n$-tuples. @Deane

@Deane that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.

If $k$ is the field of real or complex numbers, then the topology can be the standard one and the sheaf of functions can be analytic, smooth, or other standard classes of functions. For an arbitrary field, the only topology I know of is the Zariski topology.


To the pair. If it referred to only $$, it would be only a topological isomorphism, i.e., a homeomorphism. That's too weak. You want the composition of any regular function with the map to be a regular function.

$(,\mathcal{O}_)$ and $(,\mathcal{O}_)$ are isomorphic, if there exists a homeomorphism $F: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $F^*: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism of sheaves. This is a fancy way of saying that the composition of any locally regular function on $Y$ with $F$ is locally regular on $X$.

Yes.

Presumably, this is answered in the book. It goes something like but probably not exactly like this: The isomorphism defines a map from $X$ to $k^n$. Such a map consists simply of $n$ global regular functions, i.e., global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$. The fact that the map is an isomorphism onto its image implies that these $n$ functions generate the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. Conversely, any $n$ global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$ define a map from $X$ to $k^n$. If these functions generate the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, then the map is an embedding and the image is necessarily an affine subvariety $k^n$.



For a concrete example of an affine variety that isn't just a closed algebraic subset of $k^n$, let $Y$ be $k$, and let $X$ be the set $k \setminus 0$, together with its sheaf of regular functions (the restriction of the sheaf of regular functions of $Y$ to $X$). Is $X$ an affine variety? Yes, because it's isomorphic to the closed algebraic subset in $k^2$ given by $xy - 1 = 0$.

@hunter, thanks! That's a nice example. Does this mean I've stated something incorrectly? If so, I'd like to correct it.

no, your answer is good, the example is intended for OP and not for you, i should have just put it right on the question

@hunter, thanks. As my question shows, I'm far from an expert in algebraic geometry.
